# How to close collapse panel when we click link inside the panel in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried this link solution but not able to conclude. I am new to this..tried everything but all vain I want something like this what to do
[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5718/) How to close collapse panel when we click link inside the panel in bootstrap

my code:

```
            <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                   <!--  ***** -->
                 <!--  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:53px;">menu</i>
                  </a> -->
<!--                  ****** -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu"><span class="material-icons" style="font-size:40px;">menu</span></button>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Menu -->
<div id="menu" class="panel panel-default panel-collapse collapse bottom padding">
  <div class="container collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="bottom padding list-inline">
       <li><a href="#about" class="panel-collapse">ABOUT US</a> / </li>
                        <li><a href="#services" >SERVICES</a> / </li> 
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">HOTELS</a> / </li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>-->
                        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
     <div class="container bottom padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
      <p class="white">Some of our partner hotels</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="tile">
        <h3 class="title">Hilton Grosvenor House</h3>
        <p>The definition of luxury</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="tile">
        <h3 class="title">Marriott</h3>
        <p>Service paradise</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="tile">
        <h3 class="title">Ramada</h3>
        <p>For the business traveller</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center padding padding">
            <img src="images/TTB_Logo_small.png"/>
            <h1>Tourists Travel Bureau UK Limited</h1>
            </div>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).click(function (event) {
                    var clickover = $(event.target);
                    var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
                    if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
                        $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
                    }
                });
            });</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question correctly. What is the issue you are facing. Do you want to close the modal or open it. Not clear

Comment: when i click links like "About Us" etc i want to close the panel

Comment: did you try without the js code?

Comment: yes i tried... but that panel doesnt close...

Comment: what is the pblm...???

Comment: if you are using firebug, can you check if there is any error log in console?

Comment: Also, if you can put your code on jsfiddle, will be easier to debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123912/discussion-between-bangde-and-elizabeth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the link or the button give

```
data-target = "#idofthepanel"
```

Refer to the panel using id instead of class

Also,
You have given data-target="#mynavbar" , but navbar is a class and not an id.

Comment: navbar is a class but mynavbar is not a class ri8??

Comment: the code you have pasted here, myNavbar is a class. Search for myNavbar, and you will see a div has this class

Comment: did you remove the js and check now?